# How to catch an error thrown inside an imported module

Tags: python, oop, exception, python-module

I have a custom module with a function, and I am importing it to my main file. When there is an exception raised in the module, I want to catch it in the main file.

Is this possible? I'm having a hard time finding any examples of this online or in the exception documentation.

Example:

exceptionStuff.py

```
class My_Error(Exception):
    pass

def Fail_Func():
    raise Exception
```

main.py

```
from myModules.exceptionStuff import My_Error

try:
    My_Error()
except:
    print('caught')
```

The exception doesn't get caught here.

Comment: Why would this example raise an exception? `Fail_Func` is never triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reorganize exceptionStuff.py like this

```
class My_Error(Exception):
    pass

def Fail_Func():
    raise My_Error
```

And your main file like this

```
from exceptionStuff import My_Error, Fail_Func

try:
    Fail_Func()
except My_Error as e:
    print(e.__class__.__name__)
    print('caught')
```

You will successfully catch an exception of type `My_Error`.

Output:

```
My_Error
caught
```

Comment: Ah, no kidding. I had it mixed up

Comment: No worries, you were very close